# the shift key is just ignored after another key has been depressed, poor shift key. How do I detect when it is released?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I have a text input, that presently goes transparent when a user presses shift (keydown) and binds a listener for the shift key going up

ie.

```
$('#foo').keydown(function(){
      if(event.which==16){
          //make #foo transparent
          $(this).keyup(function(){
              if(event.which==16){
                 //return #foo to its former glory
                 $(this).unbind('keyup');
              }
          });
       };
  })
```

This works fine when no characters are pressed in the interim between depressing and releasing the shift key. The problem is that when shift is down and another character is pressed, the shift key seems to have been completely forgotten about. When the shift key is released, no keyup fires.

I tried triggering a 'fake' keydown with the `.which` property set to 16,  to nudge it in the right direction after other characters are pressed, but to no avail.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You're missing the `event` parameter. I guess that's just a typo in this sample script?

Comment: +1 For using "poor shift key" in your title

Comment: With the minor bug fixed, [it works flawless for me](http://jsfiddle.net/H6Tft/). What jQuery version and browser [version] are you using?

Comment: Which browser are you using? Works good for me http://jsfiddle.net/2tkDr/

Comment: Sergio, you are quite right that it works. It was total PEBCAK on my part. Apologies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While pressing <kbd>shift</kbd>, it will continuously trigger `keydown` events until you release it, so your example will bind as many `keyup` handlers as there are `keydown` events triggered. This will most likely cause all kind of weird problems.

Instead, bind both `keydown` and `keyup` to the same handler and do your magic in there:

```
$("#foo").on("keydown keyup", function (e) {
    if (e.which === 16) {
        if (e.type === "keydown") {
            // make #foo transparent
        } else {
            // return #foo to its former glory
        }
    }
});
```

See [test case on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e9qug/).

However, if you lose focus of the input while pressing <kbd>shift</kbd> and then release, it will not work as expected. One way to solve it is to bind to `window` instead:

```
var $foo = $("#foo");
var shiftPressed = false;

$(window).on("keydown keyup", function (e) {
    if (e.which === 16) {
        shiftPressed = e.type === "keydown";
        if (shiftPressed && e.target === $foo[0]) {
            $foo.addClass("transparent");
        } else {
            $foo.removeClass("transparent");
        }
    }
});

$foo.on("focus blur", function (e) {
    if (e.type === "focus" && shiftPressed) {
        $foo.addClass("transparent");
    } else {
        $foo.removeClass("transparent");
    }
});
```

See [test case on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e9qug/1/).